# fatal: repository ....... not found

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have added remote repo link with this command -

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/ni8mr/Local-Weather-App/tree/gh-pages
```

Than i have checked the remote repo version, it shows that origin is the link i have added.

Live link is here - https://github.com/ni8mr/Local-Weather-App/tree/gh-pages

Though the link is running or the repo exists, i kept getting the following error -

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ni8mr/Local-Weather-App/tree/gh-pages.git/' not found
```

How can i solve this issue ? I have checked previous solutions, but can't find the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://github.com/ni8mr/Local-Weather-App/tree/gh-pages`

is not a git-repository, it is just the webview of one of your branches. The repository is at

`https://github.com/ni8mr/Local-Weather-App.git`

Instead of just taking the link out of the browsers address bar, you should always use the URL in *Clone or download*:

[image: Clone or download]

Comment: How can i work on my web view ? I mean, if i push to my repo, will the web view be updated automatically ?

Comment: Yes, the website will update immediately when you push.

Comment: Alright, thanks i have got my answer. Special thanks for image clarification. My way of fetching url was totally wrong.

Comment: It seems better way to manage gh-pages branch is like thi - https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/.  Updating master won't affect gh-pages branch automatically.

Comment: Yes, but this site explains how to _create_ the gh-pages branch. Your repository already has a gh-pages branch though, so clone and checkout does the job.